# Running .NET core and .NET web applications on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have developed a .NET core API application which I want to deploy to a windows server. In this server, there are already several other web applications deployed using IIS which are developed in .NET framework. As I know I can deploy my .NETcore application inside IIS by installing .NET Core Hosting Bundle and doing some changes. Will this affect in any way for the already deployed applications which are developed using .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this affect in any way for the already deployed applications
>   which are developed using .NET framework?

It shuouldn't, because you'll be using a different application pool. Just because you are installing a new bundle the other projects shouln'd be affected, this is like saying that "because you have a FTP site, my other sites will stop working", which is not true.

And if I recall correctly I have seen this working before on a testing environment at my company, when we were transitioning from .Net Framework to .Net Core, so for a few months we had both up and running

Comment: It shouldn’t but it can. A server without internet connection can lead the installer to miss Visual C++ 2015 runtime and then any application pool crashes.